# Adding image format select box in typo3 v11

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have image manipulation setup on `images only` and `images and text` content elements of my  typo3 version. It shows different image formats as shown below.

[image: image manipulation]

Now I want to add a select dropdown by which one of the four image formats can be selected  and saved in the databank. I am successfully able to create a select dropdown and a new column in the tt_content table. The values are being updated in the DB. Although, I am able to position the select dropdown in the 'general' or 'access' tab of a content element

[image: select dropdown in general tab]

My problem is that, for some reason, i fail to make the select dropdown appear in the 'images' tab. Could someone one guide my why replacing 'image' with 'general' in the code below is not working?

**My code**:

```
$temporaryColumn = array(
    'image_format' => array (
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'Image format',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => [
                ['Default',0,],
                ['Quadrat',1,],
                ['Landscape',2,],
                ['Portrait',3,],
                ['Teaser',4,],
            ],
            'size' => 1,
            'maxitems' => 1,
        ]
    )
);

$table = 'tt_content';
$column = 'image_format';
$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['columns'][$column] = $temporaryColumn;

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    $temporaryColumn
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'tt_content',
    'general',
    'image_format',

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `addFieldsToPalette()`. So you are putting the field into a *palette*, not directly into a tab. This is why you must use the identifier of an existing *palette* as the second parameter.

`tt_content` has the following palettes:
[image]

As you can see, there are palettes "general" and "access" (beside tabs with the same names). But there doesn't exist a palette "image".

### Adding a new Field into an existing palette

Pick an *existing* palette and add the new field via `ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette()`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'tt_content',
    'mediaAdjustments',
    'image_format',

);
```

### Adding a new Field into an existing tab

That can be done by placing the field at a certain position in the `showitem`-list of the appropriate `type`. The easiest way is using `ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes()`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'tt_content',
    'image_format',
    '',
    'before:image'
);
```